# How to retain width and height when uploading image on AEM

Tags: adobe, aem

I am using image compression in AEM. It does compression, but changes the width and height of the image. There is option to give width and height, but I want this to be same as the original image. How do I do it.. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: when you say image compression which one of the following are you referring to 1) static renditions generated by DAM update work flow , 2) OOTB Adaptive Image servlet 3) ACS commons NamedImageTransform

Comment: Hello Sharath I am trying to use web enabled Image which is OOTB feature, Where I am specifying quality as 80% and trying to set height and width as original. but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you please update the question with more information. It is hard to understand what you are trying to do and what’s actually your problem.

Answer (score 2):

AEM is not changing your original image at all. When you upload an image to AEM a workflow (*DAM Update Asset* workflow) will be started. The workflow will create so called *renditions* (see workflow step: *Process Thumbnails*).

Renditions are different versions (size and quality) of the original image and are stored alongside the original in the JCR.

Imagine you upload an image called `Sunset.jpg` to the DAM to the path `/content/dam/prakash`. The JCR will look like this:

```
+ content/ (sling:OrderedFolder)
| 
+--+ dam/ (sling:Folder)
   |
   +--+ prakash/ (sling:Folder)
      |
      +--+ Sunset.jpg (dam:Asset)
         |
         +--+ renditions/ (nt:folder)
            |
            +--+ cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png (nt:file)
               + cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png (nt:file)
               + cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png (nt:file)
               + cq5dam.web.<width>.<height>.jpeg (nt:file)
               + original (nt:file)
```

There are a multitude of APIs to work with those renditions. Most important are:

```
Asset.getOriginal()
Asset.getRenditions()
```

See: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/Asset.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jens, I am aware that it triggers the workflow, where I have a web enabled image step, I am using a java function to trigger an event when this workflow is being processed. I am setting quality as 80% and width and height as original image.But it is not working.

Comment: Hi Jens. I know this is not how I should be contacting you but I could not find any other way. Can you please help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891213/image-quality-downgraded-after-resizing-in-aem-6-3