# Image quality downgraded after resizing in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm very new to AEM and I'm trying to reduce the image size by using `named transform image servlet` in **AEM 6.3**. After reducing the image size using `resize` property, the image quality goes down terribly.

I've also tried using attributes `sharpen` and `quality` however I'm not able to understand their proper usage even after going through the [adobe docs](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/named-image-transform/index.html).

This is the original image resolution
`1600 x 530`
This is the image configuration that I've tried so far:

`bounded-resize:width=1423&height=471&upscale=true` (using this only reduces the image quality a lot)

`quality:quality=82` (this changed nothing)

`sharpen:op_usm=3.5,20`(this distorted the image completely, sort of oil paint effect)

Above configuration maintains the aspect ration but not the quality.

Need to know what wrong I've done in this and **how do I REDUCE THE IMAGE SIZE WHILE MAINTAINING THE ASPECT RATIO AND IMAGE QUALITY**.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the order of `Image Transformers` in your transformer configuration. The documentation states:

> Order matters when defining your image transformation rules. For example, a resize then crop can yield significantly different results than a crop then resize.

I am not a 100% sure which makes more sense: `Resize and Crop` or `Crop and Resize`. But that would be easy to validate:

Create two transformer configurations. Both should just contain the resize and crop setting but in a different order. Call both of them (with the right URL) and then compare the resulting images.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I REDUCE THE IMAGE SIZE WHILE MAINTAINING THE ASPECT RATIO AND
>   IMAGE QUALITY.

As a best practice, to achieve a high image quality and small file size, start with the following combination of parameters:

fmt=jpg&qlt=85,0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=1.75,0.3,2,0

This combination of settings products excellent results under most circumstances.

For further reading and learning, Refer to [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/assets/using/best-practices-for-optimizing-the-quality-of-your-images.html)